# Compare csv file and Oracle table and highlight differences using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tab seperated csv file of around 50-80 rows (abc.csv) as follows

Column 1   Column 2   Column 3
A                            1                        XX

B                2                       YY

and a table (tblSample1)in Oracle
Tcol 1       Tcol2       Tcol3
A                            1                        XX

B                2                       ZZ

I would like to compare column 2 and 3 and highlight the difference in excel spreadsheet (which in this case is the following) 
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3           Tcol 1       Tcol2       Tcol3

B                2                       YY         B                2                       ZZ

What is the easiest way to compare the 2 and highlight the difference using excel vba?

Comment: How large is the file, and how large is the Oracle table (# of rows)?

Comment: something to this effect....Create a class/struct for the three columns, Write a compare method in the class to compare and return a result (possible enum values for return results).  Read in the CSV and put it in a collection using your class/struct.  Do the same for the Oracle DB table. loop through your collections and compare.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 50-80 rows, wouldn't a vlookup work?
i.e.

1. Import both into excel
2. Use a vlookup to get `B  2  YY` & `B  2   ZZ` into a single row
3. Use a formula like `if(a2<>a4, "error", "")`